# What is the right way to write “2 sisters and one brother”?

Tags: american-english

I would like to write a sentence like this :

I dedicate this to all my sisters and my brother

I have 2 sisters and one brother.

Shoud I write : "my sisters and my brother" or "my sisters and brothers" or "my brothers and sisters" or "my brother and my sisters"

Comment: Whatever sounds good.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't mix numerals with spelled-out numbers. Either "I have 2 sisters and 1 brother" or "I have two sisters and one brother". The latter is generally preferred.

Comment: It's 'both' sisters, not 'all' if there are only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dedicate this to all my sisters and my brother.

This sentence is already grammatical—at least based on one interpretation. However, it might sound a little strange to some people because of the use of *all* and the fact that it might not be taken as elliptical.

If taken as elliptical, the sentence in full is:

> I dedicate this to all my sisters, and I dedicate this to my brother.

In the shorter form of the elliptical sentence, the nouns are parsed as follows:

> I dedicate this to (all my sisters) and (my brother).

But if parsed differently (not treating it as elliptical), the nouns become awkward:

> I dedicated this to all (my sisters and brother).

It's this second parsing that can cause it to sound strange. Because *brother* is singular and isn't normally paired with *all*.

---

There are multiple ways of writing the sentence that could make it sound better:

> I dedicate this to all my sisters and to my brother.

Here, you explicitly repeat *to*, which had been previously omitted. This makes it clear that you're not describing a compound noun, and that *all* only applies to *my sisters*.

> I dedicate this to my brother and all my sisters.

Here, the order of the nouns is reversed, again making it clear that *all* is not being applied to *brother*.

---

You could also turn *sisters and brother* (or *brother and sisters*) into an appositive of *siblings*:

> I dedicate this to all my siblings, my sisters and my brother.
>   I dedicate this to all my siblings, my brother and my sisters.

Here, *all* clearly applies to the plural *siblings*, while the breakdown of gender is given as additional nonrestrictive information.

Comment: The last ones sound good

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, a dedication would be more personal and include names, so I would think something like:

I dedicate this to my brother, Boyname, and my sisters, Girlname and Girlnametwo.

Generally lists of varying numbers will count upwards (one of this, three of these, ten of those other), but there is no syntactic rule about it, at least not in any style guide that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

The options with "brothers" are incorrect if you have only one brother.

Grammatcially, all of the following are fine, though repeating "my" might sound a bit more formal (which is probably what you'd want for a dedication):

- my brother and my sisters
- my brother and sisters
- my sisters and my brother
- my sisters and brother

According to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=brother%20and%20sisters%2C%20sisters%20and%20brother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbrother%20and%20sisters%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csisters%20and%20brother%3B%2Cc0), "brother and sisters" is about twice as common as "sisters and brother", and as a result that order might seem more natural to readers.